# First fragment in view pager not showing because of rest api delay

Tags: android, rest, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-networking

I have a navigation drawer activity, with one fragment having a view pager and tabs. All 4 fragments are fetching data from a server. My problem is that the view pager is loading the first 2 fragments therefore my first fragment doesn't show a content at first because of the delay of the rest api. So the second fragment is being created and shown before the data in the first fragment is parsed and shown. How can I solve this?

This is my fragment container

```
public class FragmentMoviesContainer extends KFragment {
private MainActivity activity;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_container, container, false);
    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    assert activity != null;
    activity.setVisibleFragment(this);
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    ViewPager mViewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null)
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.movies);

    activity.getNavigationView().setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_movies);
    activity.setElevation(true);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return replaceFragmentMovies(Constants.STRINGS.UPCOMING);
            case 1:
                return replaceFragmentMovies(Constants.STRINGS.NOW_PLAYING);
            case 2:
                return replaceFragmentMovies(Constants.STRINGS.POPULAR);
            case 3:
                return replaceFragmentMovies(Constants.STRINGS.TOP_RATED);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.coming_soon);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.now_playing);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.popular);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.top_rated);
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }


    private FragmentMovies replaceFragmentMovies(String type) {
        FragmentMovies fragmentMovies = new FragmentMovies();
        fragmentMovies.setType(type);
        return fragmentMovies;
    }
}

@Override
public void serviceResponse(int responseID, List<KObject> objects) {

}

@Override
public void update(ModelService service, boolean reload) {
}
}
```

Here's my fragment showed in the tabs

```
public class FragmentMovies extends KFragment implements MoviesAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener {
private MainActivity activity;
private ModelService service;

private RecyclerView moviesRv;
private String type;

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    if (activity != null) {
        service = activity.getService();
        activity.setVisibleFragment(this);
    }

    moviesRv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_list);
    moviesRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    this.update(service, false);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void serviceResponse(int responseID, List<KObject> objects) {
    if ((objects != null && !objects.isEmpty()) && (responseID == Constants.UPCOMING || responseID == Constants.NOW_PLAYING || responseID == Constants.POPULAR
            || responseID == Constants.TOP_RATED)) {
        Section section = (Section) objects.get(0);
        MovieListAdapter adapter = new MovieListAdapter(getContext(), section.getMovieList());
        moviesRv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void update(final ModelService service, final boolean reload) {
    boolean hasConnection = Connection.isNetworkAvailable(getContext());
    if (hasConnection && service != null) {
        final int responseId = getResponseID();
        service.getMovies(type, "", false, responseId, reload);
    } else {
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        DialogHelper.noConnectionDialog(getContext());
    }
}

private int getResponseID() {
    switch (type) {
        case Constants.STRINGS.UPCOMING:
            return Constants.UPCOMING;
        case Constants.STRINGS.NOW_PLAYING:
            return Constants.NOW_PLAYING;
        case Constants.STRINGS.POPULAR:
            return Constants.POPULAR;
        case Constants.STRINGS.TOP_RATED:
            return Constants.TOP_RATED;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadMore(MoviesAdapter adapter) {
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null)
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movies");

    activity.getNavigationView().setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_movies);
    activity.setElevation(true);
    activity.getAddFab().hide();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

The method update calls the rest api url and fetches the data. This is a framework I created based on AsyncTask. The list of objects then is returned to the fragment parsed in the method onServiceResponse where I create the adapter and show the data. The problem is that the second fragment is being created before the method onServiceResponse of the first fragment.

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: @singh.indolia I added some code

Comment: i had a problem like this for a long time,
i solved it by assigning the fragment to the Activity after finishing all the requests

Comment: You should use Android networking library such as [Fast Android Networking Library](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Networking-with-the-Fast-Android-Networking-Library) to make the request asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make api call from the first fragment and after getting the result you should make the rest of the calls. Let me know if you need any help with the code. I think this should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

After Looking your code, there are Two things to inflate Fragments on to tabs.

> 1. Use single Fragment for all tabs.
> 2. Use individual fragment for every tab.

in the First case, if you are calling APIs form fragment that kind of problem occurs(As yours).

in the Second case APIs, the call will be in individual fragment and there will not be such kind of problem.
So the first solution to your problem is to use individual fragment for every tab.
And if really want to use single fragment for every tab then maintain the sequence of API calling for every instance of the fragment for every tab.

As you are doing in fragment like:

```
if (activity != null) {
        service = activity.getService();
        activity.setVisibleFragment(this);
    }

    moviesRv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_list);
    moviesRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    this.update(service, false);
```

in this case you are calling service and and then you are reading setting your view.
The scenario is that here API call will be in the background but the code below API call will execute. Due to that if the response of API any fragment comes then that fragment view will be populated. So Solution of that scenario is that put your API call method in fragment and then call APIs and maintain calls.
if any help just comments. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is not very explanatory, so for anyone coming across this in future, this is what I did. I am calling my REST API from the on create method of the  activity hosting the fragments and viewpager and using a single fragment class for 6 tabs by creating 6 instances of the fragment class. But the catch here is, dont set up the viewpager in onCreate, rather set it after the API call receives a successful response, after the data has been saved inside some object. So now the data is ready to be displayed within the fragment when it is first presented.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code on your one of your fragment.

```
Handler().postDelayed({

//api call 

}, 3000)
```

So that two fragment can not do api call at same time when you use viewpager.